# How to group undo operations in AvalonEdit

Tags: avalonedit

When typing quickly and then undoing by pressing Ctrl+Z, AvalonEdit's undo feature goes a character at a time instead of grouping the undo operations where typing is paused.

I've tried invoking undo groupings on text changed events but often run into exceptions due to nesting problems.

Is there a way to configure Avalon Edit to group undo-operations?